# Sequelize nodejs pass value to another function

Tags: javascript, oop, sequelize.js

Here is my function which return count fine.But I want its value to be used in my response.

```
 var PostComment = require("../models/PostComment");


    var getPostCount = function (postId,res) {
        return PostComment.findAll({where: {post_id: postId}}).then(function (comments) {
            return comments.length;
        });
    }


    module.exports = {
        getPostCount: getPostCount
    }
```

Here is my another function. Console log working fine. But I need to return value.

```
 arr.push({
                 id: item.id,
                 post_userid: item.post_userid,
                 post_sendername: item.post_sendername,
                 post_description: item.post_description,
                 attach_status: item.attach_status,
                 post_datetime: item.post_datetime,
                 post_status: item.post_status,
                 remove_id: item.remove_id,
                 attachment_list: item.tbl_post_attachments,
                 total_like:totalLikes,
                 comment_count:Samparq.getPostCount(item.id, res).then(function (commentCount) {
                       console.log(commentCount);
                 }),
                 comment_list:item.tbl_post_comments
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

SIDENOTE:
You can use the `count` method in your first code block:

```
 var PostComment = require("../models/PostComment");


var getPostCount = function (postId) {
    return PostComment.count({where: {post_id: postId}});
}


module.exports = {
    getPostCount: getPostCount
}
```

In your second code block, you're getting a `Promise` back in `comment_count`, not an actual number.

You need to first get the count, then add it to the object.

```
 Samparq.getPostCount(item.id).then(function (count) {
    arr.push({
             id: item.id,
             post_userid: item.post_userid,
             post_sendername: item.post_sendername,
             post_description: item.post_description,
             attach_status: item.attach_status,
             post_datetime: item.post_datetime,
             post_status: item.post_status,
             remove_id: item.remove_id,
             attachment_list: item.tbl_post_attachments,
             total_like:totalLikes,
             comment_count: count,
             comment_list:item.tbl_post_comments
         });
 })
```

SIDENOTE #2:
If you use async await, which is new to node, you'll be able to make it look more like your original code. *If* you're inside an async function, then your second codeblock could look like this:

```
 arr.push({
         id: item.id,
         post_userid: item.post_userid,
         post_sendername: item.post_sendername,
         post_description: item.post_description,
         attach_status: item.attach_status,
         post_datetime: item.post_datetime,
         post_status: item.post_status,
         remove_id: item.remove_id,
         attachment_list: item.tbl_post_attachments,
         total_like:totalLikes,
         comment_count: await Samparq.getPostCount(item.id),
         comment_list:item.tbl_post_comments
     });
```